# jq removing inner child node without breaking the json

Tags: arrays, json, edit, jq

Im trying to get jq to remove an inner node from a json file, the json file looks as so:

```
    {
  "etag": "14b3796c268c87553291702c808e86dfe1e53d1b",
  "rules": {
    "name": "default",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "xxxx",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "dffaa42b-3f0f-425f-a9a1-a63cd35b2517",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxx",
                "options": {
                  "key": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
                  "compress": true,
                  "ports": ""
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteria": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
                "options": {
                  "Name": "UUID",
                  "values": [
                    "dffaa42b-3f0f-425f-a9a1-a63cd35b2517"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
          },
          {
            "name": "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxx",
                "options": {
                  "key": "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx",
                  "compress": true,
                  "ports": ""
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteria": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
                "options": {
                  "Name": "UUID",
                  "values": [
                    "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ],
            "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
          }
        ],
        "behaviors": [],
        "criteria": [],
        "criteriaMustSatisfy": "all"
      }
    ],
    "behaviors": [
      {
        "name": "xxx",
        "options": {}
      }
    ],
    "options": {
      "is_secure": true
    },
    "variables": []
    },
  "warnings": [
  ],
  "Format": "xxx"
}
```

I may have muddled up the json structure, however my jq query at the moment is as follows:

```
(.rules.children[].children[] | select(.name | contains("7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17")| not ))
```

This works, excepts it it return the json excluding the child item from `.rules.children[].children[]`.

How do I have jq return the entire json file excluding the json identified in the filter?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I esentialy want to return the same json except for :
{
            "name": "7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17",
            "children": [],
            "behaviors": [
              {
                "name": "xxxx",
              }
            ],
}

Comment: You can [edit] your question instead of adding information in comments.

Comment: @Dale, you json is invalid, post the actual one

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest apologies, I have amended to include the correct Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`del/1` is capable of deleting nodes based on path expressions.

The example doesn't seem to be minimal, so let's consider:

```
  {"a":{"c":[
         {"d":{"c":[{"e":"xyzzy"},{"e":2}]}},
         {"d":{"c":[{"e":"xyzzy"},{"e":2}]}} ]}}
```

Now suppose we want to delete the objects for which `.e == "xyzz"`:

```
del( .a.c[].d.c[] | select(.e == "xyzzy") )
```

This would result in:
    {"a":{"c":[{"d":{"c":[{"e":2}]}},{"d":{"c":[{"e":2}]}}]}}

Unfortunately, jq 1.5 does not support complex path specifications in `del/1`; using a sufficiently recent version of jq, however, we can write:

```
del( .a.c[].d.c[] | select(.e | type == "string" and contains("xyzzy") ) )
```

Thus, with the above-mentioned caveat about jq 1.5, you could write:

```
del(.rules.children[].children[] | select(.name| contains("7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17")))
```

#### Workaround for jq 1.5

```
.rules.children[].children |= 
  map(select((.name? // "")
             | contains("7004389c-c47a-4611-9bd7-9f5dfe051d17")
             | not))
```

Comment: Thanks Peak, worked liked a charm. I was wondering why the del() function wasnt working, see now I was on JQ1.5.